# TypeORM: save M:N relation with custom join table in one save call

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, typeorm

Book Entity

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity({ name: 'books' })
export default class Book extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Field(() => Author)
  @ManyToOne(() => Author, (author) => author.books, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'author_id' })
  author: Author;

  @ManyToMany(() => Category, {
    cascade: true,
    nullable: true,
  })
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'book_categories',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'bookId',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'categoryId',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  categories: Category[];

  @Field(() => [BookCategory])
  @OneToMany(() => BookCategory, (bookCategory) => bookCategory.bookId, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  bookCategories: BookCategory[];
}
```

BookCategory Entity

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity({ name: 'book_categories' })
export class BookCategory {
  @Field()
  @Column({ nullable: true })
  isActive: boolean;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  bookId: number;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  categoryId: number;

  @Field(() => Book)
  @ManyToOne(() => Book, (book) => book.bookCategories, { cascade: true })
  book: Book;

  @Field(() => Category)
  @ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.bookCategories, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  category: Category;
}
```

Category Entity

```
mport { BookCategory } from '../bookCategory/book-category-entity';

@ObjectType()
@Entity({ name: 'categories' })
export default class Category extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  title: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Book, (book) => book.categories)
  books: Book[];

  @Field(() => [BookCategory])
  @OneToMany(() => BookCategory, (bookCategory) => bookCategory.category, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  bookCategories: BookCategory[];
}
```

I've used sequelize for a long time and now I'm exploring typeorm. What I want to do is save all these three entities with one payload just like sequelize.
for example in sequelize you can do something like this

```
await User.create({
  username: 'p4dm3',
  points: 1000,
  profiles: [{
    name: 'Queen',
    User_Profile: {                                       // <-------------- JOIN TABLE
      selfGranted: true                                 // extra join table field
    }
  }]
}, {
  include: Profile
});
```

what's the best way to save such payload with a custom join table field in typeorm?

Answer (score 3):

Look into saving related data when `cascade: true` is set. It's all in the docs: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relations#cascades

**Note:** Doesn't work with a custom join table.

Also note that using `cascade: true` usually isn't a great idea. For example you need to be careful never to accidentally wipe relations by saving an empty array, or not to save duplicate data. I prefer to save different things separately.

Comment: doesn't help. works ok when typeform is managing your join table, only then I'm able to save payload in single save. my concern is for saving payload with extra fields in join table. Also docs are pretty basic as compared to sequelize.

Comment: Oh yeah, it doesn't work with a custom join table like that. I don't think there's any way to make it work. Just save things separately.

Comment: Anyway, I would highly recommend saving separately in any case. The risk of bugs down the road outweighs the benefits of using `cascade: true`

Comment: I agree but a good ORM handles transactions internally for such nested creation/updation by providing a user-friendly relational API, It makes code more readable and concise IMO. anyway, thanks for the help man.